# When a nymph is killed, can items stolen by her just disappear?

Tags: nethack

My caveman had a cursed "tattered cape" (I'm sure it was MR, found in wizard bones pile) stolen by a water nymph in the final room of Sokoban.  I had to back out because I was in the broken doorway, an being triple-teamed. I left a large dog inside that had cleared most of the room (I'm guessing it killed the nymph since she couldn't teleport and was nowhere to be found) by the time I got back in. When the room was completely cleared, I couldn't find the cape.  I moved my pets downstairs, and searched the entire level to no avail. As noted, it was cursed so I'm pretty sure my pets aren't carrying it.  So, after checking the wiki about nymphs and death drops, and learning nothing new, I'm wondering if it just disappeared when the nymph died. Any info would be helpful. Also, I didn't find a potion of OD, nor a mirror.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate impressions:

- No, in general, monster inventory items do not simply vanish on death.  You may or may not get a corpse and/or death drops, but the base inventory is always preserved.
- It sounds as if you woke up the entire zoo by kicking down the door.  Don't do that if you can avoid it.  If you can get the door open silently, the monsters will still be asleep and you can dispatch them one by one.
- Because your item (probably) got dumped on the ground, we can refer to the [stash](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Stash) article for a nice list of all the ways it could have been destroyed and/or stolen:
- [Gelatinous cubes](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gelatinous_cube) are an obvious candidate.  They will happily eat any random items on the ground.
- Any monster that can wear cloaks is possibly at issue here.  In principle, such a monster could have absconded with the cloak when you ran away.  The set of monsters that wear cloaks is very roughly coextensive with [the broader definition of "humanoid"](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Humanoid) (which includes all `@`, all `h`, and a variety of other monsters).  In practice, this is moderately improbable because Sokoban is a closed-off branch of the dungeons; the monster would have had to go past you on the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you failed to notice the message "[You hear a slurping sound.](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gelatinous_cube)"

Comment: I think you may be right about the gel cube, the room was curiously empty when I returned.  PS the door was booby-trapped, part of why I had to back out.  Thx